# Stuck at booting Ubuntu

Tags: boot

This is the second time I am starting my Ubuntu. The first time is after installing the system.

I will get stuck at the message line

```
Stopping Userspace bootsplash [OK]
```

the X Window won't show up.

If I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> , I can use my account to login, and type `startX` to start X Window. But the difference is that my desktop icons and the task bar have disappeared; very different from the first time I used Ubuntu.

Anyone could help?

- Why am I stuck at that line?
- Why is the X Window different from the one I used the first time?

Comment: Is this on the Unity desktop environment?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

If that doesn't work, then do

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

on tty1, and then do step 1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer。I have tried  "service lightdm restart", it works that the Ubuntu login screen shows, but after I login, the blank screen shows, only the mouse displayed on screen.  I tried "sudo apt-get install -reinstall ubuntu-desktop", but for some files can't fetched, the install failed, what should I do now?

Comment: Can you connect to the internet?

Comment: Can connect to the internet。some files can be downloaded, but some can't.

Comment: Pres ctrl+alt+f1 and login in the tty. Then, open ~/.xsession.errors and paste the output on your question.

Comment: ** (gnome-settings-daemon:4393): WARNING **: Failed to connect context: OK
** Message: applet now removed from the notification area
** Message: using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon

Comment: compiz (core) - Warn: Attempted to restack relative to 0x180000a which is not a child of the root window or a window compiz owns
Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error No such file or directory
Please ask your system administrator to enable user sharing.

Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused

Comment: above is the latest message in .xsession.errors.